# Arduino code does not function when relays are powered

Tags: sensors, relay, atmega2560

I have a mega arduino, which is supposed to to power 4 relays using 4 touch sensors TTP 223, the relays are 5V coil and 220V. the arduino is powered by a 5 V adapter "mobile phone charger" and it powers the relay module, the problem when the relays are not connected to the 220 V the arduino and code work well; the Arduino triggers the relays, when the 220V circuit is connected and the relays are supposed to operate solenoids the relays start to work differently and sometimes shuts off, some times just blink,the relay module has 8 only 4 are used, 1, 2, 3 and 8 all are NO wired. the module is powered from the 5V  port of arduino, (https://i.stack.imgur.com/o 30IA.jpg)[image: .jd-vcc is jumped with vcc][image: the charger's output is 5V 2A] the charger's output is 5V 2A. jd-vcc is jumped with vcc

Comment: this is caused by EMI from relays. add relay (module) model and wiring to question

Comment: Does the phone charger put out enough current to drive the relays? Looks like each relay pulls more than 1/3 of a watt.

Comment: first try to wire the Ground pin next to jd-vcc and Vcc